# How do I vertically centre a div of variable height within a div of variable height?

Tags: html, css, alignment, height

I'm a bit of an amateur when it comes to CSS/HTML web stuff but I feel I am learning a lot and am grateful of all the help offered in all the stack overflow questions. I have run into a problem and been searching for a solution for hours already, apologies if this is a duplicate but I honestly couldn't find one.

Basically, I have created a simpler version of what I am working on that demonstrates my issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/qoqq39ss/

```css
.full {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.mainWide {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: grey;
}
#imageBox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
  background-color: orange;
}
#image {
  width: 80%;
  height: 190px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#textContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 65%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
</div>
<div class="mainWide">
  <div id="imageBox">
    <div id="image"></div>
  </div><!--
--><div id="textContainer">
  <h2>heading</h2>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
  </div><!--
--></div>
<div class="full">
</div>
```

Hopefully that works, first time making my own. I made them different colours to try and highlight the different divs.

The thing is, where the #image is, there would be an image, not a div. The sibling div with text in, as it varies in height due to the width of the window it can be either taller or shorter than the image. When it is taller, I need the image to be vertically centred in relation to the text, when the text is smaller I'd need the text to be vertically centred in relation to the image.

Through my searches I have seen some solutions with using a helper element of height 100% to centre elements in relation to it, though I find when I try that, it makes the helper element 100% of the height of the window as the parent element is of variable height, or maybe I am doing something wrong?

I have also seen there is an option of using tables, though I am not sure if/how that would work as I am planning of using some @media to change the image and text from being inline-blocks to blocks on top of each other for smaller screens if you get what I mean.

Apologies for the long question and if my explanation is a little off.

Many thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both `#imageBox` and `#textContainer` are inline-block elements, you can use

```css
#imageBox, #textContainer {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Currently you are using it on `#image`, but it has no effect because `#image` is a block element. You should use it on `#imageBox` instead.

```css
.full {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.mainWide {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: grey;
}
#imageBox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
  background-color: orange;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#image {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
}
#textContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 65%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
</div>
<div class="mainWide">
  <div id="imageBox">
    <div id="image"></div>
  </div><!--
--><div id="textContainer">
  <h2>heading</h2>
  <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
  </div><!--
--></div>
<div class="full">
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, that was so simple I feel kind of daft. Thanks a lot for your answer.